# Problem starting Next.js app at locallhost 7777 using yarn dev

Tags: next.js, babeljs, yarnpkg

When I try to run my localhost using `yarn dev` it shows this error:

> yarn run v1.22.4 $ next -p 7777 ready - started server on
> 0.0.0.0:7777, url: http://localhost:7777 TypeError: _jestWorker.Worker is not a constructor
> at Object.loadWebpackHook (D:\isc-web\isc-front\node_modules\next\dist\server\config-utils.js:67:20)
> at Object.loadConfig [as default] (D:\isc-web\isc-front\node_modules\next\dist\server\config.js:332:29)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at async NextServer.loadConfig (D:\isc-web\isc-front\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:112:22)
> error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command.

It was all working fine before I did `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components` even though I canceled the changes by using `git checkout -- .` but still got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cancelled dependency changes with `git checkout` your `node_modules` may still have the old dependencies installed. Try running `npm i` again to see if getting updated dependencies resolves the issue.

I can't tell much from this error message and I don't know how far along your project is... Have you seen the official Next.js + `styled-components` example? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components

Perhaps if you try setting up the library this way instead?

Comment: yup I found out that my friend was using material UI ServerStyleSheets in _document.js instead of styled-components ServerStyleSheet. thanks mate problem solved